# After changing the base url to a non-existing site . Now if I refresh my page 404 error occurs.. and admin panel is also not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I am learning Magento2 and tried creating a store view through admin panel and changed the base URL to a non existing site. now after save config I don't able to access the admin panel or my site.?? 404 error occurs.! How to change my base URL to default site's base URL using command line and revert the changes that I have made.? thank you in advance! please help me.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change base URL using Commmand line, Run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://example.com/"

php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://example.com/"

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**update:**

```
 remove all content<magento-root-dir>/var*
```

Then run below command:
    remove all content(not remove .htaccess)/pub/static/* 
Then run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then check it, if you have any issue let me know

Comment: what should I give instead of example.. I am running on a local xampp server

Comment: usually my store address is localhost/magento-2 and my admin address is localhost/magento-2/admin111

Comment: Your  need to give `localhost/magento-2` instead of `example.com`.

Comment: or its goes 404, then  you need to give  FQDN name instead of `localhost/magento-2` like `localhost-magent-2`

Comment: hurrah..!! page redirected correctly!! BUT..BUT.. contents are not listing properly. they all are unaligned..!! I think css are not rendering  but admin panel is properly rendering.!

Comment: @Priya I update my answer

Comment: The frontend worked correctly, the admin area doesn't